# Joining multiple tables in CodeIgniter query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to run a query in CodeIgniter.

The query is

```
"SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image
     WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id
          AND td_album.album_id='$id'
          AND (td_image.image_name='$name' OR td_image.image_id='$image_id');"
```

Which when I run in CodeIgniter query I write as:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('td_image')
                        ->join('td_album', 'td_album.album_id = td_image.album_id')
                        ->like('td_image.image_id', $image_id)
                        ->or_like('td_image.image_name', $image_name)
                        ->and_like('td_album.album_id',$id)
                        ->get('', $this->limit, $this->offset);
```

But I don't know why this isn't working out.

### Edit

It's throwing this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::and_like() in /home/koushani/public_html/jmssimplex.com/application/admin/models/gallery_model.php on line 189

Comment: Might want to be a bit specific. Isn't working doesn't say much. Does it return no results, the wrong results, what results are you expecting?

Comment: Perhaps consider just using `$this->db->query($query)`for more complicated queries such as the one you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Because and_like is not a active record function.so you can use multiple like in a query

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('td_image')
                        ->join('td_album', 'td_album.album_id = td_image.album_id')
                        ->like('td_image.image_id', $image_id)
                        ->or_like('td_image.image_name', $image_name)
                        ->like('td_album.album_id',$id)
                        ->get('', $this->limit, $this->offset);
```

Another way is

```
$array = array('td_image.image_id' => $image_id, 'td_album.album_id' => $id);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('td_image');
$this->db->join('td_album', 'td_album.album_id = td_image.album_id');
$this->db->like($array);
$this->db->or_like('td_image.image_name', $image_name);
$this->db->limit($this->limit, $this->offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: buddy, this query results in displaying images of all the albums while i need to show of only 1.. ur query is equivalent to..SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image
         WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id
              AND td_album.album_id LIKE'$id'
              OR td_image.image_name LIKE'$name' AND td_image.image_id LIKE'$image_id';

Comment: Dude,i just try to resolved ur Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::and_like()....

Answer (score 0):

You should write like as following

```
$this->db->select('*')
                ->from('td_image,td_album')
                ->where('td_album.album_id', 'td_image.album_id')
                ->where('td_album.album_id', $id)
                ->where('td_image.image_name='.$name.' OR td_image.image_id='.$image_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```